# What is the difference between "2013 and 2016 VSTO Add-in" and "2010 VSTO Add-in"?

Tags: c#, com, vsto, office-addins

I am about to start implementing some PowerPoint VSTO Add-in. On the Visual Studio project templates list I can see that there are two types of Add-ins: "2013 and 2016 VSTO Add-in" and "2010 VSTO Add-in". What is the difference between them? If I would like to use add-in in both PowerPoint 2010 and 2013 which one should I choose?